# How to get vim to use the same register as X?

Tags: cut-copy-paste

I would like to be able to yank and paste text from and to X clipboard (webbrowser, email client etc), is there an easy way to fuse the registers to have a single clipboard ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14225889/1945981

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean with "fusing registers" (it is like [fusing a gopher?](https://youtu.be/uvC8YTtzehk?t=342)) but I think you mean `set clipboard=unnamed`?